# Just one <td> in row to be full width (display: block) on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to style a shopping basket on a responsive site.
On small screens the design calls for the 'name' column to be full width and sit above the other values from the same table row.

In the past I've used 'display: block' to allow for styling tables on mobile - but this doesn't seem to work when just applying it to one td. What's my best option to keep the flexibility of table cells for the varying width fields whilst also making the name field full width and sit above the rest in the row?

See snippet for example.

```css
table td.name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Line Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="name">Product name, can be quite long and may span several lines</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>£201.38</td>
       <td>£604.14</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt that this will work using `display` in any way. What kind-of works is positioning the table cell absolute, and then give the other cells a padding-top to “reserve” the necessary space – but that would only be an option if you actually knew how high the content of that first cell renders. Apart from that, you might be able to achieve this by not using HTML table elements and only formatting them in a table-like way – that would allow you to insert an additional grouping element for the remaining three elements … but of course that way you’d lose table semantics …

Comment: But there’s several jQuery plugins and other similar solutions out there for “responsive” tables – maybe one of those can be of help.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe - I had come to a similar conclusion. A JS approach seems the most likely to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without javascript is putting the name into the document twice, and using media queries to hide the copy you don't need. I'm not sure how screen readers are going to handle this though.

```css
table { width: 100%; }

@media (min-width:600px) {
  .name1 { display: none; }
  .name2 { display: table-cell; }
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .name1 { display: block; }
  .name2 { display: none; }  
}
```

```html
<div class="name1">Product name, can be quite long and may span several lines</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="name2">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Line Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="name2">Product name, can be quite long and may span several lines</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>£201.38</td>
       <td>£604.14</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgk17ags/2/)

Comment: From a quick test with Voiceover this would certainly be detrimental to screen readers - but it's put me onto an idea which might work, so thanks.

Comment: do screen readers understand any css commands? like some @media query?